# Beeswarm from Reordering Categorical Variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, axis-labels, beeswarm

I am trying to make beeswarm and boxplot graphs of my data, but beeswarm is putting the categorical variables in alphabetical order when I would like them in order of treatment.

```
iMono <- beeswarm(iMono ~ Treatment, data=MyeloidLiver, ylab = "% Inflammatory",
         log = FALSE, pch=16, main = '% Inflammatory Monocytes v Treatment',
         col = rainbow(4), cex.axis = 1, cex = 1) +
  bxplot(iMono ~ Treatment, data=MyeloidLiver, add=TRUE)
```

I have tried using `levels = c()` and `labels = c()` but levels is not a graphical parameter for beeswarm and labels changes the labels without reordering the corresponding data.

Comment: If your variable is not already a factor, make it a factor and put the `levels=` in the order you like (levels= and labels= are for the factor() functions, not plotting functions). Or use `reorder()` to change the levels. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I wonder how many duplicates there are to this question? At least 10, probably 50+ and maybe 100+.